# loops and replacing in python

Tags: python, loops, replace

I seem to have hit a wall with my script. I'm trying to make it grab the text of a commentary from a website and put in some basic XML tags. It grabs everything on a page and that needs to be fixed, but that's a secondary concern right now. I've gotten the script to split the text into chapters, but I can't figure out how to further divide it into the verses. I'm trying to replace every occurrence of "Verse" in a chapter with `</verse><verse name = "n">`, with "n" being the verse number. I've tried a few things, including for loops and ElementTree, but it either doesn't work or makes every verse name the same.

I tried putting in the following code, but it never seemed to complete when I try it:

```
   x = "Verse"
   for x in para:
        para = para.replace (x, '</verse><verse name = " ' +str(n+1) +  '  " >'  )
        n = n + 1
```

The code below seems to be the most...functional that I've managed to make it. Any advice on how I should fix this or what else I might try?

```
from lxml import html
import requests
name = open("new.txt", "a")
name.write("""<?xml version="1.0"?>""")
name.write("<data>")
n = 0
for i in range(0, 17):
    url_base = "http://www.studylight.org/commentaries/acc/view.cgi?bk=45&ch="
    url_norm = url_base + str(i)
    page = requests.get(url_norm)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    para = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]//table//text()')
    name.write("<chapter name =\"" + str(i) + "\" >")
    para = str(para)
    para = para.replace("&", " ")
    para = para.replace ("Verse", '</verse><verse name = " ' +str(n+1) +  '  " >'  ) 
    name.write(str(para))
    name.write("</chapter>")
name.write("</data>")
name.close()
print "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be changing texts, when manipulating xhtml document use [xslt](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt-result-objects)